# Very large values for utime and stime for foo. Is foo still running?

Tags: process, top, ps, proc, process-management

- I am running a program `foo`
- It has been running for close to 30 days now (even more)
- Until around 10 days ago (I cannot be very exact) it used 100% of one cpu on my dual core laptop (it was at the top of `top` sorted for CPU usage)
- Now it is nowhere near the top of CPU usage (top shows 0%)
- The Top 10 cpu intensive process (according to `ps`) are:

`ps auxc | sort -r -k 3 | head -10`

```
USER       PID %CPU  %MEM     VSZ    RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME      COMMAND  
bilbo    32734 15583  0.0   17816    960 pts/16   R+    2012 24322737:01 foo
bilbo    30916 10.1   0.5 1754340  22344 ?        Sl   Jan12      128:06 chrome
root      1119  9.8   0.8  241288  31704 tty7     Ss+   2012     6707:23 Xorg
bilbo    29177  9.3  15.5 1178348  10524 ?        Sl   01:11      106:47 opera
bilbo    30635  6.3   0.5  696972  23156 ?        Sl   01:12       72:13 opera:libflashp
bilbo    25415  1.4   3.2  805156 126352 ?        Sl   Jan12       18:28 chrome
bilbo    27576  1.0   0.2  373844  11060 ?        S     2012      220:13 compiz
root     12642  0.9   0.4  342848  17156 ?        Ssl  12:12        4:38 firestarter
bilbo     3197  0.7   0.4   84832  19436 ?        Ss    2012      508:10 screen
bilbo    29956  0.7   0.2  371612  10180 ?        Sl   12:02        3:34 plugin-containe
```

- In the above table `foo` is at the top, but the `%CPU` it is being shown to use is `15583`. This value seems nonsenical.
- However I am still seeing one of the processors being utilised at near 100% capacity
- Running ps gives me the following output

`ps -eF | grep foo`

```
UID     PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD

bilbo 32734 20655 99  4454  3380   0  2012 pts/16   1184016092-19:52:29 foo
```

`ps aux | grep foo`

```
USER    PID %CPU  %MEM   VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
bilbo 32734 15602  0.0 17816  3380 pts/16   R+    2012 24322737:01 foo
```

- The output of uptime is

`up 46 days, 12:43, 19 users, load average: 1.58, 1.37, 1.82`

- It seems to me the TIME values returned by `ps`, `1184016092-19:52:29` (from `ps -e`) and `24322737:01` (from `ps aux`), are impossibly large
- The `utime` and `stime` returned by `/proc/32734/stat` are: `85714817892` and `4611685975569777027` respectively.
- I was anticipating a very large output, and I wanted to count the number of lines so I piped the output of `foo` to `wc -l`. In hindsight I should have done `tail -f` to see if the program was running.
- Nice value of `foo` is 0

**Question: Is `foo` still running?**

Output of `uname -a`

`Linux rivendell 2.6.32-44-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 17:27:10 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I am running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Happy to provide more details if required.

Comment: Perhaps using 15000% of the CPU caused foo to enter a space-time anomaly, where it spent ~2700 years of processor time and has now returned.  Question: did you just notice these weird stats now?  What was up with foo 2 weeks ago?

Comment: It was working fine, using 100% of any given processor at a time. I noticed these weird stats ~2 weeks ago.

Comment: @latexnewbie did you determine the cause for this? I'm seeing the same problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still looks at this issue, seems to me that it could be related to this reported bug:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.kernel/GbafDHrvrxE
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip.git/commit/?h=timers-urgent-for-linus&id=5a8e01f8fa51f5cbce8f37acc050eb2319d12956

Therefore only affecting older kernels.